# Ionic framework 2 (Problema Build)

Tags: android, ionic, app, build

Olá, estou tentando realizar uma build de uma app no Ionic, porém qualquer app que tento gerar a build, ele gera uma app apenas com o maps, gostaria de saber por qual motivo?

Comment: Provavelmente vc está dentro da pasta do projeto maps e esta rodando o buil. Tenta navegar até a pasta correta do projeto e depois rodar o Build. Ou melhora a pergunta para entendermos melhor.

Comment: @leopiazzoli Olá, obrigado por responder. Eu trabalho já algum tempo com projetos Ionic 1, desde que migrei para o Ionic 2, estou tendo algumas trabalhos na hora da Build, eu estou rodando na pasta correta, já realizei vários testes, porém sempre compila com o Maps, não sei por qual motivo. As vezes tenho que criar um projeto do zero, e pegar o que eu fiz de outro projeto pra colocar nesse projeto do zero, isso gera um retrabalho enorme e fica inviável para trabalhar.